# cómo guardar un observable para uso global (ehemplo ng2charts)

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy intentando guardar en una variable, datos que me vienen de una petición http, para poder usarla en el el componente de manera global. Sólo consigo guardarla de manera local(dentro del método) por lo que cuando quiero usarla fuera del método me da undefined.

La lógica es recuperr la info del back para representarla en en un gráfico del front

Cómo puedo hacer para guardarla de manera global? (dejo código)

````
public riskTable;
public riskArray;
public ultimo;
public impacto;


showChart() {
  this.testService.getRisk().subscribe(
    observable => {
      var riskTable = observable; 
      this.getData(observable)

    },
    (error) => {
      this.riskTable = null;
    },  
  );
}

getData(getData) {
  var data = getData;
  this.riskArray = data.data;
  this.ultimo = this.riskArray[this.riskArray.length - 1];
  this.impacto = this.ultimo.RISK_TEST_RESULT;
}

public bubbleChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        { 
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 15,
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 15,
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
  public bubbleChartType: ChartType = 'bubble';
  public bubbleChartLegend = true;


  public bubbleChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {

      data: [
        { x: quiero usar el dato aquí pero me da undefined, y: 10, r: 10},
      ],

    },
  ];```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es de acceso global a los datos si no de sincronía.  Cuando se trabaja con observables los datos están disponibles cuando se ejecuta el callback dentro del método `subscribe()`. Es ahí donde se tiene que colocar el código que usará los datos devueltos.

Deja vacío el array `data` así:

```
public bubbleChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    {
      data: [],
    },
  ];
```

En el método `getData()` se asignan los valores a la variable `bubbleChartData`:

```
getData(getData) {
  //resto de codigo

  this.bubbleCharData[0].data = [/* aqui llenas los datos */];

}
```

Comment: Intenté dejar la variable declarada y vacía, y después meter los datos desde el método(como haces tu) pero me daba error y tuve que recular. Desde el html no me cogía esa variable que estaría así: [datasets]="bubbleChartData"

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Me ha funcionado!! había probado algo parecido pero al poner los datos no ponía los corchetes y por eso me daba error. Lo que no me queda claro es si se puede guardar el valor devuelto de manera global en una variable. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Sí, se puede guardar. En la función `getData()` lo estás  haciendo. Pero solo estará disponible hasta que el observable emita un valor. Si antes de eso intentas leer la variable será undefined.

Comment: y si por ejemplo quisiera meter un array de valores en "x" y otro array de valores en "y" en this.bubbleCharData[0].data ?? por que un valor si me lo pilla pero si le meto los arrays solo se repesenta en el gráfico el ultimo valor del array. Gracias!!